# Categorical generalization of intersection?

Tags: category-theory

When $S_1$, $S_2$, $T_1$, and $T_2$ are sets, we know that $(S_1 \cap S_2) \times (T_1 \cap T_2) = (S_1 \times T_1) \cap (S_2 \times T_2)$. This also happens to be true when $S_1$, $S_2$, $T_1$, and $T_2$ are abstract simplicial complexes and when we replace Cartesian product with the (categorical) product of abstract complexes.

This identity looked familiar to me; namely it looked like the isomorphism $X \times (Y + Z) \cong (X \times Y) + (X \times Z)$, where $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are objects in some category with products and sums. So I'm wondering, is there some categorical generalization of $(S_1 \cap S_2) \times (T_1 \cap T_2) = (S_1 \times T_1) \cap (S_2 \times T_2)$, and if so, that probably would require some kind of generalization of intersections, in which case, is there a generalization of intersections?

Comment: In your first identity there are four terms on the LHS but in your second identity there are three. (The first identity says that two operations commute, but the second identity says that an operation distributes over another.)

Comment: Right, I understand that, I was just wondering if there is a more general version of the first identity in a similar manner that there is for the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pullbacks](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pullback). ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ah, thanks. So if you replace intersections with pullbacks in the first identity, then does it hold for any category with products and pullbacks?

Comment: @Vikram: yes. Pullbacks and products are both examples of categorical limits, and it's a general fact that limits always commute with limits (and dually colimits commute with colimits). Your second identity is more complicated because it holds in less generality, as it's an example of a limit commuting with a colimit.

Answer (score 4):

There is a categorical generalization of intersection, but it isn't documented very well on the internet (you have to visit a couple pages on nLab to get the full picture, and I can't even find a paragraph for it on Wikipedia). So it can't hurt to write it out.

Let $B$ be an object in some category. We call a pair $(A, a)$ a *subobject of* $B$ if $a:A\rightarrow B$ is a monomorphism. Now let $\{(A_i, a_i)\}_{i\in I}$ be an indexed collection of subobjects of $B$. We call another subobject $(D,d)$ the intersection of the collection $\{(A_i,a_i)\}_{i\in I}$ if

- $d:D\rightarrow B$
- for each $i\in I$ there is a morphism $d_i: D\rightarrow A_i$ such that $a_i\circ d_i=d$
- $(D,d)$ is universal for the above property

It takes a small amount of work to see that $(D,d)$ is itself a subobject of $B$ (thus $d$ is a monomorphism).

In the case of the category **Set** the indexed collection is just the subsets in question and their inclusion maps. The categorical intersection is then the set-theoretic intersection with the inclusion map. You can dualize this concept to get a generalization of union.

A little rewording and you can recognize the intersection as the pullback of a bunch of monomorphisms that share a codomain. And as Qiaochu Yuan mentioned, since limits in general commute with themselves (and pullbacks are limits), you get that products commute with intersections.

Comment: For reference, [The Joy of Cats][1] Def. 11.23 p.201


  [1]: http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf

Comment: Herrlich and Strecker authored a terrific book simply called Category Theory in Germany in 1973 that I believe is much better than The Joy of Cats. Unfortunately, it seems to have fallen out of print. It's a loss to the mathematics library.

Comment: I don't know the Herrlich-Strecker book but it seems like at least it's available digitally on https://www.heldermann.de/SSPM/SSPM01/sspm01.htm.